# Sometimes the map size is smaller than the array

Tags: c++, arrays, stdmap

Hello I've written this program and I'm wondering why is the size of the map sometimes smaller than the array even though it should be the same size due to the loop and insert.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    // init random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    int largestNum = 0;
    std::map<int, std::string> m_Data;
    std::string names[8] = { "Test", "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5", "Test6", "Test7" };

    for (auto& k : names)
        m_Data.insert(std::make_pair(rand() % 21 + 1, k));

    std::cout << "Names size: " << sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]) << " m_Data Size: " << m_Data.size() << std::endl;

    for (auto& i : m_Data)
    {
        std::cout << i.second << " " << i.first << std::endl;
        if (i.first > largestNum)
            largestNum = i.first;
    }

    std::cout << "Person with largest num: " << m_Data.find(largestNum)->second << " " << m_Data.find(largestNum)->first << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `rand() % 21 + 1` may occasionally produce the same key twice, just by chance. The map will only insert it once.

Comment: Since the map keeps its keys ordered, the largest one is always `std::prev(m_Data.end())->first`; you don't need to search for it.

Comment: A simple change to your code: `for (auto& k : names) { auto rnd = rand()%21 + 1; cout << rnd << "\n";  m_Data.insert(rnd, k));}` would have shown you the values you're inserting into the map, thus answering your question.

Comment: Hello tester! Welcome to stackoverflow. A `std::map` stores its data as key/value pairs, where each key is unique. Please take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map for more information.

Comment: Usinf`std::multimap` instead of `std::map` would give the same size as the array.

Comment: If you want the same items in a random order then you can use std::shuffle to shuffle the names then add them t' map.